# Problem with accessing www.saama.com under a proxy and without proxy

Tags: proxy

For some reasons, I am  When I open  [this blog](https://www.saama.com/blog/applications-signal-processing-machine-learning/) under [https://www.saama.com](https://www.saama.com/), I get a runtime error page like this in Firefox without using proxy :

[image]

I think this is error most be solved by using a Hoxx VPN and RusVPN chrome extensions together like this:

[image]

So how this site could detect my  IP (both of them are the same)  and these IPs are not [my real IP](https://www.whatismyip.com/) :

[image]

and what is proxy filed in this  [IP finder site information](https://www.iplocation.net/find-ip-address):

[image]

why the proxy field is different in chrome with VPN and Firefox without VPN  and I can not access the site information as you can see here :

```
Proxy   5.78.57.183, 149.126.78.20
```

but the banned site said:

```
Your IP5.78.57.183|Proxy IP45.60.54.103(ID 10108)
```

Is this site using  IPv6 which don't detected in some online IP finder sites, for banning me?

And if I use tor I could access to its containers?

So if tor also could not hide my IP, it most be ...

I have seen the tour of  https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com and seen:

> A network under someone else's control

Sentences, so I don't asked there. Also, is here proper to ask this question?

**Update:**

It is solved after almost 10 minutes later trying accessing the restricted site by chrome with already VPN, So does it mean those VPNs don't worked?

It could be and I have not tried to check the chrome IP with some IP finder sites at that time if I have done that work it could clear the answer better. Does there could be any possibility for Encountering this situation?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: well i'm not sure but perhaps this question fits better at [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/), but it has clearly nothing to do with Tor.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because look at my comment: 
well i'm not sure but perhaps this question fits better at [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/), but it has clearly nothing to do with Tor.